# Visual Studio Code - How to jump by word with [Alt]+[Left/Right]

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

I've started using Visual Studio Code on MacOS.

Jumping with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd> is really annoying as it jumps by full identifier instead of just a word.

Examples:

- ▼create_foo() <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> create_foo▼()
- ▼createFoo() <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> createFoo▼()

I'd like e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to do the thing above and to modify the behaviour of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> so it jumps by word.

My desired behaviour:

- ▼create_foo() <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> create_▼foo()
- ▼create_foo() <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> create_foo▼()

**Solution:**

My final `keybindings.json`config with the added <kbd>Shift</kbd> (select) options:

```
[
    {
        "key": "alt+left",
        "command": "cursorWordPartLeft",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
    },
    {
        "key": "alt+right",
        "command": "cursorWordPartRight",
        "when": "editorTextFocus",
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+alt+left",
        "command": "cursorWordPartLeftSelect",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+alt+right",
        "command": "cursorWordPartRightSelect",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+left",
        "command": "cursorWordStartLeft",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }, 
    {
        "key": "ctrl+right",
        "command": "cursorWordEndRight",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+ctrl+left",
        "command": "cursorWordStartLeftSelect",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "shift+ctrl+right",
        "command": "cursorWordEndRightSelect",
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
]
```

Comment: Anyone have an issue with this not working for the `ctrl` shortcuts using `vscode 1.43.2` and `macOS Catalina 10.15.1`? Any other keybindings not including `ctrl` are fine...

Comment: I'm using a Mac and then into Windows via MS RDP.  I don't want to lose the Mac gesture with my Logitech mouse.  And I always use <ctrl> left and right arrow to navigate text in Windows.  I'll try to retrain my brain with Mark's answer below.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You are looking for

```
cursorWordPartRight
```

which is bound to <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Right</kbd> is bound to a "`Go Forward`" command, you could delete that binding and use it for the     `cursorWordPartRight` command.

```
{
    "key": "alt+right",
    "command": "cursorWordPartRight",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
  },
  {
    "key": "alt+left",
    "command": "cursorWordPartLeft",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
  }
```

It may require that each language parser support it though.  It does work in JavaScript.

```
cursorWordPartLeft (command exists but is unbound by default).
```

There are also these other unbound relevant commands:

```
cursorWordPartRightSelect
cursorWordPartLeftSelect
cursorWordPartStartLeft
cursorWordPartStartLeftSelect
```

Comment: thanks. why did you use the `editorTextFocus` option?

Comment: Because "alt+right" has some other keybindings, so as to reduce possible conflicts.